# $f\circ f$ is linear implies $f$ is linear

Tags: functional-equations

I saw a question that asked for the possible values of $f(-1)$ if $(f\circ f)(x)=4x-12$.

The solution uses the fact that if the degree of $f$ is $n$, the degree of $f\circ f$ is $n^2$, and concludes that $f$ must be linear i.e. be of the form $ax+b$. The rest is easy.

I understand that this is the case if $f$ is a polynomial, but the question doesn’t state that. What if there exists a weird function with logarithms, trigonometric functions etc. that is not linear but its composition with itself is linear? In other words, maybe the composition “cancels out” the weirdness. Obviously, involutions are a trivial example since the composition is $x$.

My question is: Is there a function $f$ that is not linear, but $f\circ f$ is linear and is not the identity function?

Comment: Would a self-inverse function like $f(x)=\dfrac {1-x}{1+x}$ do?

Comment: ... or $f(x) = 1/x$, or  ...

Comment: I assume that you want the domain to the the whole $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I think there is the tacit assumption that the domain of $f$ is all real numbers (since the domain of $f\circ f$ can be $\Bbb R$ but is limited to whatever the domain of $f$ is).

Comment: Then how about $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$

Comment: @player3236 : This question is explicitly about missing assumptions...

Answer (score 4):

For $a,b>0$, let
$$f(x)=-\frac{a+b}2x+\frac{b-a}2|x|=\begin{cases}-ax&x\ge0\\-bx&x\le 0\end{cases} $$
Then $$ f(f(x))=abx,$$
so $f\circ f$ is linear. If $a\ne b$ and $ab\ne1$, then $f$ is not linear and $f\circ f$ is not the identity.